# apache proxy doesn't work

Tags: apache, docker, debian

I've got a problem with my apache configuration.

I'm running a apache2 in a docker container.
In the same container is a webrick running on port 3000

What I want is that when someone calls subdomain.mydomain.de
There should be a pass through to

subdomain.mydomain.de:3000

I've done this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

added this in default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName mydomain.de
  ServerAlias *.mydomain.de
  ProxyPass / http://subdomain.mydomain.de:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://subdomain.mydomain.de:3000/
</VirtualHost>

 a2enmod proxy
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But all what I got is this:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Comment: Anything useful in `/var/log/apache/error.log` or whatever the error log location is? If error logging is not enabled for this vhost: `ErrorLog /var/log/apache/error.log`

Comment: did you check the error log of webrick? i didn´t see anything bad in the apache config but if apache can´t connect to a backend or gets an exception, you get similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for this problem is:

> sudo a2enmod proxy 
>   sudo a2enmod proxy_http 
>   sudo service apache2 reload